# How to manage ng-show events in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am managing an angular ng-show event on a button click to show a div element in the DOM. How can I reset the to hide the div if user clicks anywhere else in the DOM other than on the button. 
I am currently using angular ver- 1.5.8. Help is highly appreciated.

```
<div class="panel-wrapper collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <a class="btn btn-success btn-outline m-t-10 collapseble" style="margin:1px" ng-repeat="author in authorsData" ng-click="showRoles(author.id, author.contribution_role)">{{author.name}}</a>
                 </div>
                 <div class="m-t-15" ng-show="roles.length > 0">
                   <button class="btn btn-outline btn-info btn-xs waves-effect" style="margin:1px" ng-repeat="role in roles">{{role}}</button>
                 </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: show us some of your code.

Comment: <div class="panel-wrapper collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <a class="btn btn-success btn-outline m-t-10 collapseble" style="margin:1px" ng-repeat="author in authorsData" ng-click="showRoles(author.id, author.contribution_role)">{{author.name}}</a>

                     </div>
                     <div class="m-t-15" ng-show="roles.length > 0">
                       <button class="btn btn-outline btn-info btn-xs waves-effect" style="margin:1px" ng-repeat="role in roles">{{role}}</button>
                     </div>
                  </div>

Comment: I wanted to hide the div under ng-show control when a user click elsewhere on the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-blur directive for this.

Example:

```
<div >
    <input type="button" value="Click" ng-click="set=true" ng-blur="set=false"/> 
</div>
<div ng-show='set==true'>
    Clicked
</div>
```

Hope you are able to manage **ng-show** events using this code.